# How can I convert these FlatButton to Switch

Tags: flutter

How can I convert these two buttons to a switch.

```
      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () => firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('messages'),
        child: const Text('Subscribe'),
      ),

      FlatButton(
        onPressed: () => firebaseMessaging.unsubscribeFromTopic('messages'),
        child: const Text('Unsubscribe'),
      ),
```

Comment: What did you try? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
Switch(
  value: subscribed, 
  onValueChanged: (value) async { 
         if(subscribed) {
           await firebaseMessaging.unsubscribeFromTopic('messages');
         } else {
           await firebaseMessaging.subscribeToTopic('messages');
         }
         setState(() => subscribed = value); 
  });
```

Please note that this needs to be a `StatefulWidget` with a bool `subscribed` to keep your state. That probably needs to be initialized somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use toggle.

[Check Here](https://pub.dev/packages/toggle_switch)

you can get selected tab index and set your logic there.